# Is the electron of carbon identical to that of hydrogen? How to prove it?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, popular-science

I am still confused with whether, for example, the electron of carbon is exactly identical to that of hydrogen.

How can the scientist confirm this?

Comment: You separate the electrons from both types of atoms and compare. No difference has ever been found. You can also transfer electrons from hydrogen to carbon and see if you get a different atom. That also doesn't happen.

Comment: As far as anyone can tell, all electrons in the universe are indistinguishable.

Comment: I placed an answer here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11826/are-all-electrons-identical/225571#225571